# $|X| \le |Y|$ iff there is a injection from $X$ to $Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I am reading Set Theory from https://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/99015/mod_resource/content/1/320lecturenotes.pdf . The author calls an ordinal number "cardinal" if it is not equipotent to any ordinal less than itself. For a set $X$, cardinality of $X$ is defined to be the unique cardinal equipotent to $X$.

Now, let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. I want to show that $|X|\le |Y|$ iff there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$.

Here is my attempt. ($\Rightarrow$) Let $\alpha =|X|$ and $\beta = |Y|$. Then by definition there are bijections $f: X\to \alpha$ and $g: Y \to \beta$. Since $\alpha \le \beta$, we have that $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ by definition of ordinals. Let $i_\alpha$ be the inclusion mapping of $\alpha$ into $\beta$. Then $g^{-1} \circ i_\alpha \circ f$ is an injection from $X$ to $Y$.

($\Leftarrow$) This is the part which I am unable to prove. Suppose that there is injection $h: X \to Y$.

After several failed attempts, I do not know how to finish the proof. Hints will be appreciated!

---

EDIT: I tried a proof. I would appreciate it someone can verify it!

Let $h: X\to Y$ be an injection. Let $g: Y \to |Y|$ be a bijection. Then $\text{ran} (g\circ h) $ is a subset of $|Y|$. So $\text{ran}(g\circ f)$ is a well ordered set with respect to its membership relation. Let $\gamma$ be the order type of  $\text{ran} (g\circ h) $. Let $F$ be an order isomorphism from $\gamma$ to $\text{ran} (g\circ f)$ . So $F(\delta)\ge \delta$ for each $\delta < \gamma$. Consequently, $\delta \le |Y|$ for each $\delta < \gamma$. Hence, $\gamma\le |Y|$.

Since $|X|\le\gamma$ (because $X$ is equipotent to $\gamma$), we have that $|X|\le |Y|$.

Comment: The direction you are trying to prove is just part of Definition 52 in the text, so there is nothing to prove. "Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.  Then we say that the cardinality of $A$ is less than equal to the cardinality of $B$, denoted by $|A|≤|B|$, if there exists an injection from $A$ to $B$."

Comment: @SteveKass At that point in the notes, cardinals weren't even defined. It's just a "naive" approach to cardinality. Now that cardinal number are defined (Definition 59), I want to prove that there exists an injection from X to Y if and only if the cardinal number of X is less than or equal to the cardinal number of Y as the author states in the following paragraph.

Comment: Ah, I see. Given an injection $h:X\to Y$, first prove the stronger statement that $\alpha \le \beta$ for *any* ordinals $\alpha$ equinumerous with $X$ and $\beta$ equinumerous with $Y$. If you can do that, then it will follow for $|X|$ and $|Y|$.

Comment: @SteveKass Can you please verify my attempt that I added?

Comment: Your attempt looks overly complicated. I'm not saying it's wrong, but for example, I don't know what it means to say a set is "a well ordered set with respect to its membership relation," and I don't know that you need that idea (or the idea of an order isomorphism) for this. Did you try what I suggested in the previous comment, which I think is easier and just uses compositions of functions similar to what the other direction used?

Comment: @SteveKass I don't think your claim is correct. For instance if I take $X=\omega +1$ and $Y=\omega$ then obviously there is a bijection between $X$ and $Y$ since both are countable but then if your claim was right, we would have $\omega +1 \le \omega$ which is not true.

Comment: @SteveKass By definition, ordinals are well ordered set with respect to their membership relation and also transitive. So any subset of an ordinal inherits the well ordered property and that is what I meant by saying that $\text {ran } g \circ f$ is a well ordered set with the membership relation.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Yes, my idea doesn't work. Sorry I can't be sure if your proof is correct. :(

Comment: @SteveKass Thanks for your help. Some help is better than no help :)